# Back button display previous user activity in Spring MVC

Tags: spring-mvc, session, spring-security, back-button, spring-webflow

My web application builds on Spring MVC with spring security configured with annotation based on the user roles. If the session timeout automatically after some time without doing any kind of interaction, session going to be expired and user logout, redirect to login page. And login with same user redirect to the previous URL. e.g: (Previous module: Creates employee). Now the issue is that when session timeout or logout, and login again with another user and press browser back button, previous user activity it show. Ok, if again logging the with same user, but should not perform the previous user activity.

Following is the flow of page redirection to simplify the issue.

1. `User 1 > Login > Dashbord > Create Employe > Employee List >Logout.`
2. `User 2 > Login > Dashbord > (Press Back Button) Employee List > (Again Press Back Button) Create Employee > (Again Press Back Button)  Dashboard.`

Above page redirection flows right if login with same user (User 1).

May be this issue can solve using the spring web flow, but how to use spring web flow.?

Anybody can help me how to handle the back button issue.????

Answer (score 0):

You may try removing history on logout and setting up cache as given in below URL.

[How Disable Browser Back Button only after Logout in mvc3.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14437987/how-disable-browser-back-button-only-after-logout-in-mvc3-net)